# Connect Google Play Services, Android Studio + Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, service

I created a new Cordova project and installed all new plugins via terminal. I'm trying to run my app in Android Studio via the simulator and am receiving all these errors:

[image]

I read online that these are due to not connecting Google Play services. So I went to `Project Structure` -> `My App` -> `Library Dependencies` and added the newest version of Google Play. I also tried to add a line in my app's build.gradle:

[image]

I am still receiving build errors. Should I not be adding a compile line in the build.gradle file? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by adding dependencies { } like so below:

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
 }
```

Comment: where did you put this?